# How to create a Hello world extension in Magento?

Tags: magento

I would like to create my first Magento extension, is there any tutorial about "Creating simple Hello world extension" for Magento. In mean time if i find any such tutorial in Google, I will post in this.

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world

Comment: Hi Alan, This tutorial gives me steps to create a Helloworld module.. but what i needed is to create an extension, so that i can install it in someother magento server just like installing extensions from Magento connect without copying the respective files manually..?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood.  Try the information here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/225016/

Comment: Thank you Alan i am going through the link..!!

Comment: Please have a look at the following thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591373/how-to-create-a-hello-world-extension-in-magento

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a simple Hello World module creation tutorial:- http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/

Furthermore, you can use module creator for easy and initial module setup:- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Answer (score 7):

For beginners the best one out there, is this article from Smashing Magazine: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

Answer (score -5):

1. Declare your extension in `app/etc/modules`
2. Put PHP code in `app/code`. which directory you can declare in your `Company_Module`
3. Create layout in `app/design/frontend/default/default`.

Comment: user is asking for tutorial. not for guideline here